# Setting Datetime timezone in Rcpp

Tags: r, datetime, timezone, rcpp

I want to add 30 secs from input R POSIXct object with UTC timezone and output the POISXct object with same timezone in the Rcpp function, but the output timezone is my system timezone(CST).

I don't want to change the locale setting in R environment, but I didn't find the setting about timezone in Rcpp::timezone.

Here is my Rcpp code:

```
sourceCpp(code = "
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Datetime TimeExample(Datetime x) {

     return( x + 30 );

}")

NowTime = as.POSIXct("2017-03-21 13:35:23","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")
TimeExample(NowTime)
## > "2017-03-21 21:35:53 CST"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You really do not need Rcpp for this, but you can of course use Rcpp for it (maybe as part of a bigger problem).

You generally want the `*Vector` types, here `DatetimeVector`, and I recommend the rewritten one you can opt-into now, and which will become the default later this year:

```
// use new Datetime vector API
#define RCPP_NEW_DATE_DATETIME_VECTORS 1

#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
DatetimeVector TimeExample(DatetimeVector x, std::string tz) {
  DatetimeVector y(x);
  y = y + 30;
  y.attr("tzone") = tz;
  return(y);
}

/*** R
NowTime <- as.POSIXct("2017-03-21 13:35:23","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")
TimeExample(NowTime, "America/New_York")
*/
```

You see that we set the tzone via `attr` as we would in R.

When I source this I get:

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("/tmp/robinchen.cpp")

R> NowTime <- as.POSIXct("2017-03-21 13:35:23","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")

R> ShiftedTime <- TimeExample(NowTime, "America/New_York")

R> ShiftedTime
[1] "2017-03-21 09:35:53 EDT"
R>
```

and you see that it comes out as Eastern time as desired (even though I am in Central Time).

You can do all that the R level at basically the same speed with the same number of operations.

Comment: Is there a new `Datetime` class too? I am having problems, because `Datetime` is loosing the "tzone" attribute and the seconds from epoch is in my local timezone. For example, `Datetime a = y[0]; a.getHours();` is giving the hours in my local timezone regardless of `y`'s timezone.

Comment: Please provide a minimally complete and reproducible example as an issue ticket at the GitHub repo.

Comment: It wasn't quite what I thought. The seconds from epoch is according to UTC, as it should be. But `getHours()` is also according to UTC, which doesn't seem right to me, so I will still issue a ticket.